# Permission denied in ~/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/server.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-valet

I'm getting this issue with Laravel Valet suddenly:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(/Users/Myself/.config/valet/config.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Users/Myself/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/server.php on line 60

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Users/Myself/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/server.php on line 86
404 - Not Found
```

I tried this common solution:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.composer/vendor
```

I also tried:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Users/Myself/.config/valet/config.json
```

Lastly I made sure the composer path is in my `.zshrc` file:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"
```

I tried deleting the `.config/valet/config.json` file and recreating it.

Tried updating composer globally, running brew doctor, and restarting valet.

Tried `brew remove composer` followed by `brew install composer`.

Tried `chmod 0777 ~/.config/valet/config.json` and got these permissions but still have the same error:

```
Access: (0777/-rwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (  501/    Myself)   Gid: (   70/    _www)
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This series of commands fixed the issue:

1. `brew uninstall composer`
2. `rm -rf ~/.composer`
3. `valet uninstall`
4. `rm -rf ~/.config/valet`
5. `valet unsecure --all`
6. `brew update`
7. `brew install composer`
8. `composer global require laravel/valet`
9. `valet install`
10. `valet park` (on site dir)
11. `valet secure` (in repo dir)

Comment: I don't think these steps are in the right order. How do you run `valet` AFTER removing ~/.composer ..? That said, I merely deleted the valet config directory, re-initialized it with `valet install` and that did it. It was probably a PHP config issue stemming from a `brew upgrade` I ran a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue in my local too.

I changed the `~/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/server.php` file `VALET_HOME_PATH` variable value with the correct `.valet/config.json` path. Then it's working well.

Reference link: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/getting-valet-not-found-error?page=1&replyId=166071